# Risks in allowing users to upload HTML/JS files

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, whitelist

We're designing an online aracade for HTML5 games.  The users can upload a zip file which contains their game.

On upload, the zip is unpacked by the server and each file is looped checking it's extension against a white list allowing:

- .html
- .js
- .png
- .jpg
- .appcache
- .m4a
- .ogg

(Games must be made in our game editor which exports those files).  This should prevent people uploading zips, server side script files etc etc.

The games are then moved onto our static cookieless domain (scirra.net).  When the game is played on our scirra.com page the game is displayed in an iframe pointing to the scirra.net domain.  This should prevent malicious JS from accessing scirra.com cookies.

Is this iframe technique and whitelist comprehensive enough to prevent anything malicious from being done?  Note we can't really screen each JS file so we should assume people are going to try uploading malicious JS.

Comment: i know this might cause some flack, but you need an apple-like approval process.

Comment: I think it also depends on what type of security are you interested in.  Are you interested solely in protecting your servers or are you also interested in being sure that you are not hosting malicious code to your game players.  If you are considering both cases, then you may have to do a bit more work to verify that the user isn't crafting (even within your editor) some crafty JavaScript that might exploit the gamer.

Comment: @Daniel, it's just not really realistic for us.  We have a large audience of people who would want to use this and would like a way to sandbox each game so that it's safe.  I'm just really wondering if a JS run in a frame on a different domain can do any damage.

Comment: @RLH what sort of JS could exploit the gamer?  We're interested in both.

Comment: @Tom: `window.location = http://somevirusinfestedsite.com` for starters. `while (true) alert('haha');` (and it's variants) to stick another one out there.

Comment: @Matt I think HTML5 enabled browsers generally handle repeated alerts OK now, I don't feel I need to worry about them.  The window.location one is good though will think about that.  I mainly concerned about the iframe being able to interact with the parent window.

Comment: @TomGullen: You've also got `window.top.location = http://somevirusinfestedsite.com`

Comment: See Matt's post.  I'll be honest, I'm a hobbiest JS/HTML5 dev with limited knowledge on the subject.  However, I try to be aware of the various exploits that are out their as an informed user of these techs.  Matt's exploit is probably the most realistic. Searching for of windows.location in the JS or HTML files wouldn't be enough.  The dev could hash a JS string that would do something similar, unhash it on the users machine, and then pass it to an Eval() call. Run each game in a sandbox and human test them. Unless you are a sizable site, this shouldn't be unreasonable.

Answer (score 4):

The [origin inheritance rules for iframes](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Origin_inheritance_rules) will prevent the scirra.net iframe from interfering with scirra.com.

This however,  does not prevent **all** attacks.  In effect you are introducing a stored XSS vulnerability.   XSS can be used to introduce browser based attacks,  such as exploiting buffer overflows in ActiveX components.  Exploiting falws in Flash, Adobe reader or Microsoft Office.

You should consider running an anti-virus on the scirra.net content.  Although this won't prevent all attacks.  The ifram'ed page could redirect or introduce another iframe that contains malicious content.

As Cheeksoft pointed out.  Apps will be able to affect each other with XSS.  A malcious app could gain access to another application [offline storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784/which-browsers-support-html5-offline-storage) or obtain other data embedded in another app.   Forcing each app to have its on sub-domain will mitigate this issue.  You could setup a DNS record to point *.scirra.net to your server and take care of the domain name within your web app.

Comment: And if you host all the submitted apps on the same domain, you may have stopped stored (and reflected) xss against your own domain, but one malicious app can perform xss attacks against all the other apps. Serve each from their own dynamically generated domain name and try and persuade developers to always set their cookies to myapp.scirra.net and never set just scirra.net.

Comment: @Cheekysoft  yeah thats a good point.  I wasn't thinking about that vector,  there might be valuable information stored in the other apps or in the off-line js storage systems.

Answer (score 0):

What about incorporating some screening features in the game editor that you supply? Screen out references to external URLs, perform code validation, check for encoding, etc.

You would have to lock down the zip file to prevent tampering, but that might be a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else reading this, there is an **experimental/beta** iFrame sandbox attribute:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox

Note it only currently works on Chrome and Opera.  This allows you to specify some restricting features.

However in the case of our question we've scrapped the idea and have decided that because we are in the advantageous position of having a game creator program we can simply get the user to upload the Json data which is guaranteed to be safe with the core engine features being hosted by us.

Any plugins we can manually review and approve for use which is a much smaller job than manually approving every game.